# VBA EXCEL .AutoFilter logic

Tags: excel, vba, filter

This is my scenario:

[image]

What I would like to do is to filter all the rows that contains the word **food** (this word could change, so per example it could be **drink** or **cars**)

This is my code far enough

```
    With Sheets("Foglio1").Range("A1:F20")
    .AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=Sheets("Sheet1").Range("H2")
    .AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:=Sheets("Sheet1").Range("H2")
    .AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:=Sheets("Sheet1").Range("H2")
    .AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:=Sheets("Sheet1").Range("H2")
    End With
```

Comment: Is a helper column an option?

Comment: You can insert what you like BigBen

Comment: Then you can add a helper column that uses `COUNTIF` to count if the specific word is found in that row, e.g. `=COUNTIF(C1:F1,$H$2)>0` and drag down. Then filter on `TRUE` in that column.

Comment: Sorry BigBen I could not understand what you are trying to say to me. Can you provide me an example? If you could answer my post would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done with a helper column.

In `G1`, add the formula `=COUNTIF(C1:F1,$H$2)>0`, and drag down to `G19`.

Now you can filter on column G and the value `TRUE`.

I will leave the VBA implementation to you.

[image]